# Most efficient way to extract tables from Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift, query-performance

I have large table (~1e9 rows, ~20 columns) in a AWS Redshift instance. I would like to extract this entire table through PostgreSQL in order to pipe the data into another columnar storage. Ideally, columns would be extracted one column at a time while maintaining an identical row ordering - as it would facilitate a lot of work on the receiving end (columnar).

How can I ensure that the series of SQL queries stay exactly aligned with each other? Thanks!

Ps: I am aware of the *unload through S3* option, but I am seeking a PostgreSQL option.

Comment: The answer somewhat depends on the destination database. As in, there's probably tools out there to do exactly what you want

Comment: The destination database is an in-house columnar data storage service internally developed at Lokad. :-)